# How does one convert an integer to a float while data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, string-formatting, android-databinding

I have an Int which contains a decimal number in units of tenths, so for example my int holds `308` to represent the decimal number `30.8`.  I want to use data binding to display this number in a TextView along with some other text.  My TextView has the following text entry:

```
android:text="@{String.format(&quot;my value: %.1f&quot;, @{viewModel.myValue}.toFloat()/10.0f)}"
```

This fails to build with the following error:

```
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method toFloat() in class java.lang.Integer","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_you.xml","pos":[{"line0":163,"col0":54,"line1":163,"col1":84}]}
```

The value in question is defined like so:

```
private val _myValue = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val myValue: LiveData<Int> = _myValue
```

I thought this meant it was a Kotlin integer and i could call Kotlin functions on it, but apparently it's a java integer and I can't?

Why can't I call `toFloat()` there?  How can I display this Int as a decimal number?

Comment: Why are you using the `java.lang.Integer` in the first place?  Use the Kotlin `Int`.

Comment: Try `Float.valueOf()` in your case

Comment: @RaBaKa78: Please read the *entire* question, my value IS defined as a Kotlin `Int` and not as a `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari: That does work!  Thanks.  Do you have any idea why that works but not `.toFloat()`?

Comment: `.toFloat()` is a kotlin syntax. but `Float.valueOf()` is from java. In XML Java works

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari: Even though the project code is in Kotlin and the data types are from Kotlin the xml is in java?

Comment: Yes. That would be right.

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari: I had no idea, thanks.  So far you've given me the most complete answer to my question, if you want to psst it as an actual answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xml if you want to use casting you will have to do it the way you do in JAVA

Here to convert it to float
try using ->

```
android:text="@{String.format(&quot;my value: %.1f&quot;, Float.valueOf(@{viewModel.myValue})/10.0f)}"
```

`.toFloat` is to be done in kotlin classes. In xml still you have to use JAVA

Answer (score 3):

This might help you.

DataBindingConverter.kt

```
class DataBindingConverters {
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun convertIntegerToFloat(value: Int?): Float {
            return value/10.0f
        }

    }
}
```

XML import

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="com.package.DataBindingConverter" />
    </data>
.....
```

Bind to View

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="@={DataBindingConverter.convertIntegerToFloat(viewModel.myValue)}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, it will work.

```
android:text="@{String.format(&quot;my value: %.1f&quot;, @{(Float)(viewModel.myValue)}/10.0f)}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I get `error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Float
                        floatViewModelGearWeight = ((java.lang.Float) (viewModelGearWeightGetValue));`

Comment: you have to use kotlin not java

Comment: I am using Kotlin.  What you've written does not work in Kotlin.